# Python: copied lists keep changing elements in all other lists, although list(), copy() etc. are used

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, copy

I have a bug in my code and I have tried to fix it using different approaches, still it does not work. I have scaled down my original code to the essential part of it below. I use a textfile as the input and it contains the number of vertices (first line), number of edges (second line), number of colors (third line) and the remaining lines consist of two numbers (separated by a blank space) representing the edges. What is important are the edges.

**INPUT**

```
6
5
3
6 2
2 3
3 4
4 6
6 2
```

**CODE**

```
# An instance of m-Coloring Graph problem (NP-hard) Karp-reduced to an
# instance of the Casting problem.

#! /usr/bin/python3

def subgraph(v,aux1,aux2):
    print(nhoods)
    sg = list(aux2[v-1])
    aux1.remove(sg)
    sg.remove(v)
    for i, nhood in enumerate(aux1):
        try:
            aux1[i].remove(v)
            aux2[i].remove(v)
        except ValueError:
            pass  # do nothing!        
    for vertex in sg:
        sg.extend(subgraph(vertex,aux1,aux2))
    return sg

line = 0
edges = []
inputs = "testfile.txt"
f = open(inputs,"r")
for i in f.readlines():
    line += 1
    if line == 1:
        V = int(i)
    elif line == 2:
        E = int(i)
    elif line == 3:
        m = int(i)
    else:
        edge = [int(n) for n in i.split()]
        if edge in edges:
            pass    # Removes double edges
        else:
            edges.append(edge)

conv = []   # Connected vertices
for edge in edges:
    for vend in edge:
        if vend in conv:
            pass
        else:
            conv.append(vend)   # Stores none-isolated vertices

# Create lists of neighbors/neighborhoods for each vertex
nhoods = []
for v in conv:
    nhood = []
    for edge in edges:
        if v == edge[0]:
            nhood.append(edge[1])
        elif v == edge[1]:
            nhood.append(edge[0])
    nhood.append(v)
    nhoods.append(nhood)

# Create list of connected subgraphs
aux1 = list(nhoods)
aux2 = list(nhoods)

#for nhood in nhoods:
#    aux1.append(nhood)
#    aux2.append(nhood)

SG = []     # List of subgraphs
while aux1 != []:
    v = aux1[0][0]
    SG.append(subgraph(v,aux1,aux2))
```

Now, when I run the code, what I want it to do is create copied lists of the  `nhoods` list called `aux1` and `aux2` (at line 62 in the code). (I later use these for the prupose of finding connected subgraphs in the input graph). However, when I modify one of the copied lists `aux1` or `aux2` the `nhoods` changes! But this should not happen when I am using the list() function, right? I have tried using the copy() function and a for-loop with no better results. To me it seems that the lists refer to the same spot in the memory, but why? Is it that the elements of the lists (which are lists) are refering to the same memory spot? How do I solve this?

I hope I did not miss anything, otherwise just ask, thanks in advance!

Best regards//

Comment: You probably want to read this https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I somewhat figured out the issue you are facing is mutability property of the list. Also you need to understand the difference in Soft copy and Hard copy. Whatever you have followed are Soft copy approaches. Since you have mutable elements inside a mutable object, Hard copy is required. For Hard copy one approach you can follow is using `copy.deepcopy` method.

```py
import copy

...
aux1 = copy.deepcopy(nhoods)
aux2 = copy.deepcopy(nhoods)
```

Now all of the elements of `aux1` & `aux2` are created on different memory than that of `nhoods`.